# How do I reload an AJAX modal node add form without altering the behaviour of the original node add form?

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm trying to edit the behaviour of node submit form (node type = 'class') but *only* when the form is submitted within an ajax modal window. Importantly, after the form in the modal window is submitted the modal window should just close (or even better reload a blank form and display a status message confirming the previous submission). This would enable the user to carry on submitting 'class' nodes before closing the modal window and returning the existing page.

I managed to get the below module code (adapted from [here](https://agaric.coop/blog/display-forms-modal-dialog-drupal-8)) to simply close the modal window, but this also seemed to alter the original node add form (accessed at: /node/add/class) so that the page did not redirect to the newly published content following submission of the form. How could I adapt the module code to only alter a new form display mode with machine name: node.class_modal_form_mode (leaving the default form at node/add/class unaffected)?

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CloseModalDialogCommand;
#use Drupal\Core\Ajax\RedirectCommand;

/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 */
function modal_form_example_help($route_name, RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  switch ($route_name) {
    // Main module help for the modal_form_example module.
    case 'help.page.modal_form_example':
      $output = '';
      $output .= '<h3>' . t('About') . '</h3>';
      $output .= '<p>' . t('Display a form in a modal window using the Drupal Ajax API') . '</p>';
      return $output;

    default:
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function modal_form_example_form_node_class_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_modal_form_example_ajax_submit';
  $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'use-ajax-submit';
}

/**
 * Close the Modal and redirect the user to the homepage.
 *
 * @param array $form
 *   The form that will be altered.
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 *   FormState Object.
 */

function _modal_form_example_ajax_submit(array $form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new CloseModalDialogCommand());
  #$response->addCommand(new RedirectCommand('/'));
  $form_state->setResponse($response);
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Simply check the current page path/URL. Modal wont have `/node/add`

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit for me? Where would I add the current path/URL?